# No se me devuelve la ubicación correcta de Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

No me está devolviendo la ubicación correcta `Latitude` y `Longitude` de Firebase.

En la app el primer usuario guarda una ubicación de un evento `Latitude` y `Longitude` en Firebase y el segundo usuario que quiere saber dónde se va a celebrar el evento le da a un `TextView` que tiene el post en `MainActivity.java` y lo llevo a `MapActivityUser.java` donde se pone un marcador donde se vaya a celebrar el evento. El problema es que no se me está devolviendo la ubicación correcta, y encima es la misma ubicación para todos los posts.

Alguien ve algún error en mi código?

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MapsActivityUser.java**

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        final String postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (post.getPostid().equals(postid)) {
                        LocationHelper locationHelper = snapshot.getValue(LocationHelper.class);
                        if (locationHelper != null) {
                            double latitude = locationHelper.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = locationHelper.getLongitude();
                            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on Map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: en lugar de pedir todos los post, hacer un foreach y luego preguntar si es igual a tu post id, podes pedirle a firebase que te devuelva ese post en especifico. Firebase cobra por datos enviados y no hay necesidad aca de que pidas todos los post, te va a salir caro.

Comment: El else esta puesto en el if incorrecto, te va a salir un toast por cada post que no es igual al post que estas buscando.

Comment: @ErickSilva vale, el else lo he cambiado, pero podrías echarme una mano con la primera sugerencia que me has dado? No sé cómo hacerlo exactamente.

Comment: DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").getChild(postId);

Comment: @ErickSilva querías decir ```DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postId);```, verdad?

Comment: @ErickSilva de todas formas no me está funcionando, no sé... La app no se cierra ni nada, pero no me devuelve la ubicación correcta. Me devuelve un marcador en África y no he creado ningún evento en África...

Comment: podrias agregar los valores de latitud y longitud que estas obteniendo al momento de crear el marker

Comment: @ErickSilva sí tío, me lleva a África que creo que es el Latitude y Longitude default que ellos ponen. Una ubicación en el ecuador... No entiendo porqué acabo allí... Siempre acabo allí

Comment: Insisto, ¿Podrias agregar los valores de latitud y longitud que estas obteniendo? Los valores por default son Lat=0 y Lon = 0

Comment: @ErickSilva son 36.62 and 119.30 siempre. Que el marcador se pone justo al lado de Africa a la izquierda...

Comment: 36.62,119.30 es china, no africa y tampoco coincide con los datos de firebase, porfa debugea bien y asegurate de los datos que estas obteniendo